# BASIC tags: Dialect or Machine?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

[This question](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/269/278) is tagged with [atari-basic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atari-basic), but is actually about different dialects of [basic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic) on an [atari](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atari) machine.

My understanding was that the [foo-basic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foo-basic) tags were for different dialects, and the [basic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic) tag (which I created) was for the [basic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic) language in general.

Should this question be retagged, and is the [basic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic) tag summary I just wrote correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked question is about measuring time on Atari 8-bit computers, using Atari BASIC. The question contains a number of screenshots of different dialects of BASIC, but they are just benchmarks from other *computers* used to illustrate the aim of the requested code. Think of it as "How would I write code equivalent to this in Atari BASIC?" — the example code most definitely does *not* give the desired result on Atari 8-bit micros, in any dialect available.

Arguably the question could be retagged [atari](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atari) [basic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic), but that feels like nit-picking to me since the only dialect you can be sure to have on 8-bit Ataris is [atari-basic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atari-basic). Microsoft BASIC and Turbo-BASIC XL were also available but rather rare back in the day. (And this raises another question: is [atari-basic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atari-basic) the Atari BASIC dialect, or all BASIC dialects available on Atari computers? Should the latter be expressed as [atari](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atari) [basic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic)?)

I do think your general [basic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basic) tag has its place, and that your tag summary is correct; it's just not quite appropriate here.